# Pattern (string) allows characters only one time

Tags: java, android, string, pattern-matching

I want to check if my string contains only allowed characters. Everything works properly for example `7B`, `77B` or `7BBBB`, but when I input something like this `7B7` or `7BB2` it's not matching.

Everything work fine, but when integer is last character it's not working.

Could You tell me what is wrong with that code?

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*[a-f]*[A-F]*");
matcher = pattern.matcher(stNumber);
if (matcher.matches()) {...}
```

Comment: What exact rule are you trying to match for? It sounds like you don't need regex if you're doing validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mix numbers and chars in a various order you need sth like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\da-fA-F]*")
```

Comment: If the answer worked please select it as correct. That way people whit the same problem would find what to do and you'll reward the person that spent time and neurons to help you.

Comment: I know, but I need to wait few minutes after this option activate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try it this way?

```
// Compile this pattern.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*[a-f]*[A-F]*[0-9]*");

// See if this String matches.
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("num123");
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(true);
}
```

[Source](http://www.dotnetperls.com/pattern-matches)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to verify that the string only has digits and letters and nothing else?

If so try using the following:

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z-A-Z\\d]*$");
matcher = pattern.matcher(stNumber);
if (matcher.matches()) {...}
```